# rvm install 1.9.3 on cygwin hangs during yaml config

Tags: ruby, cygwin, rvm

I am on cygwin and I have installed `rvm` by `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`. Now I run `rvm install 1.9.3` which produces this output:

`$ rvm install 1.9.3
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /cygdrive/d/usr/root/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /cygdrive/d/usr/root/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /cygdrive/d/usr/root/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.`

After which it just hangs (seems to hang because it sits there for a long time). The log file contains this output:

`[2012-07-26 03:10:52
]  ./configure --prefix="/cygdrive/d/usr/root/.rvm/usr"

./configure: line 382:  9000 Segmentation fault      expr a : '(a)' > /dev/null 2>&1
./configure.lineno: line 382:  6448 Segmentation fault      expr a : '(a)' > /dev/null 2>&1
./configure.lineno: line 382:  7648 Segmentation fault      expr a : '(a)' > /dev/null 2>&1
./configure.lineno: line 382:  7944 Segmentation fault      expr a : '(a)' > /dev/null 2>&1
./configure.lineno: line 382:  4116 Segmentation fault      expr a : '(a)' > /dev/null 2>&1
./configure.lineno: line 382:  6348 Segmentation fault      expr a : '(a)' > /dev/null 2>&1
./configure.lineno: line 382:  9548 Segmentation fault      expr a : '(a)' > /dev/null 2>&1
./configure.lineno: line 382:   784 Segmentation fault      expr a : '(a)' > /dev/null 2>&1
./configure.lineno: line 382:  3360 Segmentation fault      expr a : '(a)' > /dev/null 2>&1
./configure.lineno: line 382:  9304 Segmentation fault      expr a : '(a)' > /dev/null 2>&1`

Looks like my cygwin is not installed right. please help.